# How to run Laravel 5 framework successfully for new learner

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to explore `Laravel 5` php framework but don't understand how to run with Hello World application.

I am using `WAMP (On E Drive)` Server on Windows 10 operating system and here is php server details:

- Apache 2.4.9
- PHP 5.5.12
- MySQL 5.6.17

I have tried following steps to install `Laravel 5` on my local system but not working.

- Download Composer (Install composer by [Composer-Step.exe](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe)) `https://getcomposer.org/download/`
- Via composer create project I have run this command on `cmd` but not working I am having confusion regarding this command `composer create-project laravel/laravel e:\wamp\www\ {directory} 5.0 --prefer-dist`

When I have run about command on `cmd` I got following message:

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Too many arguments.

create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

Need your support to run `Laravel 5` for first time and also give me your suggestion if required for `Laravel` framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a free introduction to Laravel, this one is for the Laravel 5 version, the current one is 5.1 but to learn the basics is pretty good
[Laravel 5 Fundamentals](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals)

This is from Laracasts, you could find a lot of info here but you have to subscribe to the site, you won't regret it if you subscribe

Answer (score 0):

There are things that you should know before you install laravel.

1. You need internet to conveniently install laravel. The faster the better.
2. You need Composer to install Laravel. Download and install the
   Windows installer based setup.
3. You need to know your computer's user name for the system environment. In my case I'm in windows 10  [C:\Users[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin]
4. You need a server, in my case I'm using XAMPP with Apache server.
   (You may use other php server you want as long as you know where to
   go).
5. You can find the official Laravel tutorial at Laravel 5.0
   Installation page.

In the Laravel installation page, you have an option to use its own virtual host homestead. But if you are more comfortable using your prefer server then you may go for it.

check out [Installing Laravel 5 with XAMPP or Wamp on Windows Platform](http://anytch.com/installing-laravel-5-with-xampp-or-wamp-on-windows-platform/) with Windows 10 for more simpler way.